# Stinking water from ONE faucet

Tags: plumbing, water

We have just built a house with a new > 35 ft deep well. The water tested clear of bacteria and sulfur, etc. We have ONE faucet out of 10 sinks in the whole house that stinks. It is ONLY the cold water in one of the master bath sinks. If I let it run for a minute, the smell goes away. Obviously all our pipes are new. What could be the cause and what would be the fix?

Comment: Can you diagram your [drain-waste-vent system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drain-waste-vent_system)?

Comment: Had the same problem Replace the supply hose. Especially if it's one of those white flex hoses.

Answer (score 2):

Need more information.  Sorry for doing this as an answer but the alternative was a raft of comments.

Can't speak for your location.  Here we can get a chemical water sample bottle from our local public health office, fill it, and send it in.  A month later we get a report.

If you can do this with the affected faucet, you can find out WHAT is generating the stink.  Hydrogen sulfide (rotten egg smell)  Sulfur dioxide (burned match smell)  Dead animal (rotting meat) smell?

---

How long does it take for the smell to regenerate?  E.g.  You ran it until the smell stopped at 8:00.  Does it stink again by 9?

---

Where does this line run relative to other lines?  Is it the last tap on a run or is it a side tap?

---

Are your water lines copper or plastic?

---

Do you have water hammer traps?  (A capped vertical pipe branch.  They tend to collect dissolved air, and act to reduce the ***Clunk!!!*** when someone shuts a tap abruptly.  A dead mouse in one could add a certain bouquet to the water.)

Answer (score 1):

We had stinking cold water coming out of only one faucet in the whole house. After running the cold water a few minutes it would quit smelling. Tried pouring bleach down the drain , running the cold water for a while ...nothing seemed to work. Finally we changed the hose and presto! Seemed that our hose was a bit to long. It had a loop in it . Guess the water would get trapped and that's where the stink came from. So glad we finally figured it out and such a simple solution :)

Comment: Hello, and welcome  to Home Improvement. Where is this hose that was too long? And, if it's the  supply for the faucet, wouldn't it be always full of water?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. Replacing the hoses didn't help.  Neither did replacing the faucet itself.  Finally I installed a water filter ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B072YVNRZN/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072YVNRZN)). Turn off the water, fill the resevoir with bleach, turn on the water and run through the various taps in the bathroom one full resevoir of bleach each. If you can't detect when the bleach is coming out by smell, get water dye (Green Water Tracing & Leak Detection Flourescent Dye - 1 Gallon) and a blacklight flashlight.  I tried doing this running bleach through the one smelly tap, but the cure never lasted until I did all the bathroom fixtures.  Have fun!